# как получить часовой пояс клиента (браузера) из http запроса

Tags: php, http, клиент-сервер

Можно ли каким либо образом получить часовой пояс клиента при обычном http запросе get, т.е. пользователь в строке запроса браузера вводит адрес и отправляет запрос, без каких либо дополнительных параметров

Comment: Погуглите "IP to Timezone", и это возможно только используя сторонний сервис или сторонюю библиотеку для идентификации по IP. https://ipgeolocation.io/timezone-api.html

Answer (score 1):

Установив файл cookie с помощью JavaScript, который будет содержать часовой пояс клиента. Он довольно длинный, но потому, что довольно многословен. Я реализовал подобное решение в одном из своих приложений, и оно работает довольно хорошо.

Вы также можете отправить часовой пояс через Ajax на сервер и заставить его делать все, что вам нужно, с этим. Или, если вы не делаете с ним никаких вычислений на стороне сервера, просто примените клиентскую сторону часового пояса там, где это необходимо. Действительно зависит от вашего варианта использования.

В дополнение к этому, я предлагаю вам позволить посетителю самому установить свой часовой пояс и сохранить его в файле cookie или сеансе.

Вот пример вам
Получение часового пояса браузера

```
var timezone_offset_minutes = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
timezone_offset_minutes = timezone_offset_minutes == 0 ? 0 : -timezone_offset_minutes;

console.log(timezone_offset_minutes);
```

Отправ это в запросе

Сторона пхп

```
$timezone_offset_minutes = $_GET['timezone_offset_minutes']

$timezone_name = timezone_name_from_abbr("", $timezone_offset_minutes*60, false);

echo $timezone_name;
```

Надеюс смог помочь))

Comment: Благодарю). да это очень важная информация, но я имел в виду без дополнительных действий. Например я впервые я делаю запрос без каких либо курс. Вообщем как я понял такая информация не передаётся